# How to style CSS for Header with Logo going to the very left and the login going to the very right without affecting the content below the header?

Tags: html, css

I want to design a website for mobile devices such as Smartphone or tablet. The website should have a Header and a Content under the Header.

I want that the Header will have a Logo going to the very left and the login going to the very right, like the below picture:.
[image]

So here is what i tried

```
<div >

       <div class="{style.column-left}">...</div>
       <div class="{style.column-right}">...</div>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="{style.content}">...</div>
```

CSS

```
.column-left{ float: left; }
.column-right{ float: right;}
```

The above CSS code aligning the header correctly but the content did not align to the left, see the error picture:

[image]

**So how to fix it so that the content will not be affected by the header?**

Comment: Just a tip: *Never* use `<br />` tags for spacing elements. Set a `margin` property instead.

Answer (score 0):

Take this class:

```
.clearfix::after{display:'block';content:'';clear:'both'}
```

Apply it to your container element like so:

```
<div class="clearfix"> .. </div>
```

Change nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that when you use `float`, the element is removed from the normal flow of the page, so it does not occupies its normal space anymore. Also, a floated element floats over the next element. Since you've floated both divs, you're causing the visual issue.

A solution is to float only one element. In this case, it's better to float only the login, because left alignment is the default, and your logo is going to be on the left side without the need of float.

Just remember to invert the markup position for the login div to be placed before the logo one, so it can float over it to the right.

```css
.column-right{ float: right;}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="column-right">login</div>
  <div>logo</div>  
</div>
<div class="">
  this is my content
</div>
```

Comment: if i removed the "colomn-left" then the header was messed up as the logo did not go the the very left. Did u tested ur code?

Comment: ok, seem it is almost works but the "Login" Right Panel does not align with the Logo as it was put bellowed a bit

Comment: Did you invert their placement in the markup? Login div must be placed before the logo div

Comment: If the Login was placed before the Logo then this time the Logo got pushed down, see the err picture: 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/D52qe.png

Comment: but if i put logo and login inside <div class="{style.column-container}">, then it is better